# Создание потока. Его начальная функция. Неявный параметр функции

Tags: c++, многопоточность, qtcreator

```
//здесь ошибка: C3867: "MainWindow::GlobalPlus": нестандартный синтаксис;
// используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член
HANDLE pThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,GlobalPlus,0,0,NULL);

//У функцию же есть один неявный параметр?  
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE MainWindow::GlobalPlus()
{
    QString str = QString::number(this->GlobalData);
    //EnterCriticalSection(sec);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        GlobalData+=3;
        Sleep(1);
        GlobalData-=3;
        str +="\n"+QString::number(this->GlobalData);
        ui->labThread1->setText(str);
        ui->labThread1->update();

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, в языке С++ имя функции-нестатического члена класса само по себе не является легальным выражением. То есть просто `GlobalPlus` - это бессмыслица. Получение указателя на нестатический член класса всегда требует указания квалифицированного имени этого члена, а также требует явного применения оператора `&`

```
&MainWindow::GlobalPlus
```

Во-вторых, функция-нестатический член класса в принципе не может выступать в роли функции потока. Поэтому то, что вы пытаетесь делать - в принципе невозможно сделать в таком виде. Скрытый параметр `this`, конечно, существует, но не станет чудесным образом выполнять роль параметра `LPVOID lpParameter` функции потока.

В-третьих, с чего это вдруг у вас функция потока возвращает указатель `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`? Функция потока в WinAPI обязана возвращать `DWORD` и ничего другого.

Поэтому не занимайтесь ерундой, делайте вашу функцию статическим членом вашего класса с явно указанным параметром `LPVOID lpParameter`. И, разумеется, передавайте указатель на соответствующий объект в `CreateThread`. (Какой объект у вас там является "соответствующим" мне отсюда не видно.)

```
/* static */ DWORD MainWindow::GlobalPlus(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
  MainWindow *this_window = static_cast<MainWindow *>(lpParameter);
  // И далее работаем с `this_window`
  ...
```

Более элегантной реализацией того же может быть

```
/* static */ DWORD MainWindow::GlobalPlusCallback(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
  MainWindow *this_window = static_cast<MainWindow *>(lpParameter);
  return this_window->GlobalPlus();
}
```

При этом в `CreateThread` вы указываете `GlobalPlusCallback`, а ваша оригинальная `GlobalPlus` остается без изменений (кроме, разумеется, возвращаемого типа).

P.S. Если вы сделаете функцию статической, то все, что я сказал в "во-первых" можно будет в данном случае проигнорировать.